# Базовый тип(по умолчанию) класса перечисления

Tags: c++

В подавляющем большинстве случаях перечисляемые константы определяются от нуля или от не большого положительного значения. По сему появляется вопрос на уровне спортивного интереса:

**Почему базовый тип класса перечисления по умолчанию есть `int` а не `char`** (ввиду того, что значения вполне вместятся в байт и можно сэкономить память)?

Comment: Потому что очень и очень давно int был базовым типом для всего. Вообще всего. И через си оно перекочевало в с++ и иногда проявляет себя, если забыть указать тип. Но с++ любит явное указание, а вот чистый си пользуется полным ходом. И если что, на char сильно память не сэкономишь

Comment: `int` по умолчанию только для `enum class`. Для обычных `enum` вроде зависит от кмпилятора.

Comment: Вопрос был про enum class